# PHP union operators output is incomprehensible

Tags: php, arrays

Can anyone explain why when I write the following code:

```
$arr = array("define", "two dimensional", "three dimensional");
$var = array("variables", "constant");
$allArray = $var + $arr;
print_r($allArray);
```

I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => variables
    [1] => constant
    [2] => three dimensional
)
```

But I was expecting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => variables
    [1] => constant
    [2] => define
    [3] => two dimensional
    [4] => three dimensional
)
```

Comment: Then your expectation has been wrong.

Comment: Ok , there is a mistake in my question can you tell me why it skipped the first two position from the second array and jumped to the string "three dimensional", What happened to string define and two dimensional.

Comment: This is explained in the documentation of the functions: double keys are NOT overwritten. That means if a key already exists, then the second candidate is skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array union operator is defined in the manual as follows:

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

So for basic, numerically-indexed arrays, only the "extra" values from the right-hand operand (`$arr` in your question) will be used. This is why you're only seeing *three-dimensional* added in.

If you want to keep all values, you should look at using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead. For numerically-indexed arrays, it will preserve (and re-index) all values.

See https://eval.in/893020 for a demonstration of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the keys consider the following code

```
echo str_pad('>===== Union', 60, '=')."\n";

$arr = array("define", "two dimensional", "three dimensional");
$var = array("variables", "constant");
$allArray = $var + $arr;
var_dump($allArray);


echo str_pad('>===== Union With Assoc', 60, '=')."\n";


$arr = array('one'=>"define", 'two'=>"two dimensional", 'three' => "three dimensional");
$var = array('four' => "variables", 'five' => "constant");
$allArray = $var + $arr;
var_dump($allArray);

echo str_pad('>===== Replace ', 60, '=')."\n";

$arr = array("define", "two dimensional", "three dimensional");
$var = array("variables", "constant");
$allArray = array_replace($var,$arr);
var_dump($allArray);

echo str_pad('>===== Replace With Assoc', 60, '=')."\n";

$arr = array('one'=>"define", 'two'=>"two dimensional", 'three' => "three dimensional");
$var = array('four' => "variables", 'five' => "constant");
$allArray = array_replace($var,$arr);
var_dump($allArray);

echo str_pad('>===== Merge ', 60, '=')."\n";

$arr = array("define", "two dimensional", "three dimensional");
$var = array("variables", "constant");
$allArray = array_merge($var,$arr);
var_dump($allArray);
```

Outputs:

```
>===== Add==================================================
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "variables"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "constant"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "three dimensional"
}
>===== Add With Assoc=======================================
array(5) {
  ["four"]=>
  string(9) "variables"
  ["five"]=>
  string(8) "constant"
  ["one"]=>
  string(6) "define"
  ["two"]=>
  string(15) "two dimensional"
  ["three"]=>
  string(17) "three dimensional"
}
>===== Replace =============================================
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "define"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "two dimensional"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "three dimensional"
}
>===== Replace With Assoc===================================
array(5) {
  ["four"]=>
  string(9) "variables"
  ["five"]=>
  string(8) "constant"
  ["one"]=>
  string(6) "define"
  ["two"]=>
  string(15) "two dimensional"
  ["three"]=>
  string(17) "three dimensional"
}
>===== Merge ===============================================
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "variables"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "constant"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "define"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "two dimensional"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "three dimensional"
}
```

You can see it here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0a08a0a31cf4c91ecba835ef86bf483751acda0

As you can see using `+` works like `replace()` instead of `merge()`.

This is the expected behavior:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand
>   array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the
>   left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the
>   right-hand array will be ignored.